# Connecting two nodes one on rasberry pi and other on Ethereum

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, peers, raspberry-pi

The rasberry pi and my laptop are using same network

From my laptop  `admin.addPeer("enode from above rasberrypi")`

```
enode://6179e58bb512415a76e4169dd25ae5a171e34069660b233cf79dabd3581d8dd1221a7f3a5e5d64251aa7e8ac20eda5430e42eed161e68cb05d05e6c3cab68a6e@publicip:port
```

When i run admin.nodeInfo.enode
i get a different IP and when i check it from my  http://www.whatismypublicip.com/ it returns some different IP
Which IP should i use while connecting the 2 nodes 
while net.peerCount still remains 0 even if it returns true .
Is their any configuration that needs to be taken care of ?
What is the command if i want to include genesis also at the time of node creation

Comment: If you're operating from the same network, you need the private IP address of your raspberry pi. You can get that by using `ifconfig`. The `admin.nodeInfo.enode` shows the private IP address and the website you referred to shows the public IP address. Hence, the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both nodes, you need to run the same genesis commands:

`geth --datadir /where/ever init /your/genesis.json`

And the same launch command:

`geth --datadir /where/ever --networkid A_NUMBER`

Your `admin.addPeer()` command is correct.
Make sure that the long hex part of the enode of your laptop and Raspberry are different. If they are the same, delete the `/where/ever/nodekey` file and start again.

As for the Raspberry's IP, you should get it with `ifconfig` instead. Confirm that your laptop can connect to Geth on the Raspberry with `telnet IP_ADDRESS 30303`.