# What geth command options have been depreciated/removed?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network, genesis, devp2p

I'm looking at [this tutorial](http://billmarino2.github.io/general/2015/12/09/JURIX-2015-setting-up-an-ethereum-testnet.html).

It includes this line:

```
geth --genesis %PATH%/Ethereum/testnet/genesisblock.json --datadir %SAME_PATH%/Ethereum/stateinfo --networkid 1234 --nodiscover console
```

As I understand it, the `genesis` command option has been depreciated.

My attempt at re-interpretation, using `init` is:

```
geth  --datadir "%SAME_PATH%/Ethereum/stateinfo" --networkid 1234 --nodiscover init "%PATH%/Ethereum/testnet/genesisblock.json" console
```

However this fails with

```
I0214 19:15:23.475842 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling:
 libusb: not found [code -5]
```

**What is the correct re-interpretation of the above line?**

Is there a set of before and after use-cases for depreciated commands?

**EDIT - full console coutput:**

```
geth  --datadir "c:/mypath/testnet/" --networkid 1234 --nodiscover init "c:/mypath/testnet/genesis.json" console
I0214 19:15:23.475842 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling:
 libusb: not found [code -5]
I0214 19:15:23.476842 cmd/utils/flags.go:613] WARNING: No etherbase set and no a
ccounts found as default
I0214 19:15:23.477842 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file h
andles to c:\mypath\testnet\geth\chaindata
I0214 19:15:23.529845 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:c:\mypath\testnet\geth\chain
data
I0214 19:15:23.530845 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file h
andles to c:\mypath\testnet\geth\chaindata
I0214 19:15:23.566847 cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:132] successfully wrote genesis block
 and/or chain rule set: ba4fe4055a968c1b05a1254289164e7665cfef89782dcc7dcaec2e5e
4edc83a6
```

It then exits - which I wasn't expecting. I was expecting a console or an ipc instance to attach geth to...

Comment: "_Is there a set of before and after use-cases for depreciated commands?_" - I very much doubt it :(

Comment: Realised I need two separate geth commands as per this: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8212/820

Answer (score 3):

You do everything right with init. As far as I understand you updated geth to last release, where hardware wallets support was added. So it requires libusb to be installed in your system. You should install it.